# How to keep a particular group of a expandable list view always open

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to keep a particular group of a expandable list view always open.

I have a Expandable list view and I want it be open if a user selects something from the child view.

I can access the groupId on click of child, but I do not know how to keep it aways opened after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the id of the child's parent group and override `ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener()`.

If it is the group that you want to keep open then call `expandGroup()`.